# karate-name not working for nested feature file calls

Tags: karate

I have a feature file A.feature calling B.feature. The kara-name are defined in B.feature and I am executing the Gatling test using A.feature file. In this use case, the karate-name is not showing up in the Gatling report. However, if I use B.feature containing the karate-name, the protocol.nameResolver is working fine. Is there any limitations on this nested feature file use case?

I have the below code in the gatling performance test scenario which works fine when directly calling the B.feature file containing the karate-name.

val protocol = karateProtocol(
)
protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

//Calling B.feature file from A.feature

```
* def verifyPayment = call read('classpath:common/servicecall/B.feature@verifypaymentcall') { amount: '#(amount)', currencyCode: '#(currencyCode)', formOfPaymentType: '#(formOfPaymentType)', ccSecurityValue: '#(ccSecurityValue)',  pos: '#(pos)'}
```

//In B.feature file karate-name is declared as shown in below code snippet.

```
  @verifypaymentcall
  Scenario: verify payment api call
    Given url smartRouterPXUrl
    And header karate-name = 'Verify_Payment_API'
    * header Accept = 'application/xml'
    * request verifyPaymentRQ
```

Regards
Debayan

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code. in such cases, the ONLY way to get help is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue